# Null Ponter while running selenium code in JUNIT 4

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run this code but i get the null pointer exception. 
I am using Junit 4.10 and Selenium 2.24.1 JARS.

The exception is in @After " driver.quit(); "

When i run the same code in my home with Desktop it seems to work fine. The only difference is that i run Eclipse Indigo @ home and i run Eclipse Ganymede here. But i dont think that should be an issue, unless i am mistaken.

Stack Trace:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at framework.Ford.tearDown(Ford.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
     org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)

Thanks.

```
public class Ford {

    static private WebDriver driver;
    static private String baseUrl;
    static private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFord() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/finance");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("AA")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("f");
        driver.findElement(By.id(":1")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, try to post only the most relevant pieces of the code. Here, for example, the `isElementPresent()` method is never used.

Comment: agreed..i am a noob....didnt know the etiquette...will keep that in mind

Comment: The testcase itself doesn't seem to be relevant, too :). Could you please post the stacktrace of the Exception (or at least the interesting parts)?

Comment: added stack trace......hope it helps

Comment: Huh. Not really. Are there any additional lines? I'm particularly looking for any `org.selenium` or more `org.junit` lines. We need to know where that NPE comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try after making this change in the tearDown() method -

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    if (driver != null)
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}
```

This might solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Hari....that solved that issue....but i got a noclassDefFoundError....but i am going to try to analyze that myself....thanks again

Comment: fixed it...seems like i needed to add selenium standalone jar